# what is the mean of " minDate:new Date(-86399999136e5) " in air datepicker

Tags: jquery

i want to set min year=1990 and max year=2020 in air datepicker calender, i have Air datepicker.min.js, in this js file min date define as

> minDate:new Date(-86399999136e5)

and max date define as

> maxDate:new Date(86399999136e5)

so i am unable to understand this no"86399999136e5", can anyone tell me about this, and how to set max year and min year in air datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

86399999136e5 is scientfic notation for the number 8,639,999,913,600,000. So why did the person who wrote that code pick that number? They were working from the [range of `Date` given in the JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range):

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC. In time values leap seconds are ignored. It is assumed that there are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day. ECMAScript Number values can represent all integers from -9,007,199,254,740,992 to 9,007,199,254,740,992; this range suffices to measure times to millisecond precision for any instant that is within approximately 285,616 years, either forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is slightly smaller: exactly -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC. **This gives a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC.**

*(my emphasis)*

Apparently the author of that code decided to take a day off each end of the range, since 8,639,999,913,600,000 is 8,640,000,000,000 minus 86,400,000.

*(Side note: You can write 8,640,000,000,000,000 as 864e10.)*